# Using PowerPoint or Keynote can I switch between presentations seamlessly?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, iwork-keynote

I want to have a presentation loop 6 slides as people walk into the meeting but then I want to switch seamlessly to the main presentation without showing the desktop. Is this possible with either PowerPoint or Keynote?

Many thanks
Steven

Comment: Welcome to Super User. A common mistake new users make here is they fail to include details of what they have already researched or attempted. Please [edit] your question to include this. If you haven't tried anything yet, I know there are lots of resources available when you search for "*powerpoint loop intro until keypress*". Give something a try and share what the results are. We can help from there (if needed).

Comment: Thanks Charlie, to be honest I've only done a Google search but struggled to find an an. I'll do some more search first.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple in PowerPoint.  I do it frequently, usually like so:

I'll usually make the first slide of the main presentation some kind of welcome screen or logo or the like.

Somewhere on it, I add a rectangle and give the rectangle an action setting of hyperlink to other presentation, and link it to the looping presentation.  Once the link is all set up, I give the rectangle no line and make its fill 100% transparent so it's invisible.

In the main show, go to the slide show setup dialog, set:

- Presented by a speaker (full screen)
- Loop continuously until Esc

Now you can start the main show, click the rectangle (now invisible) to start the loop show.  When you want to return to the main show, press ESC to dismiss the looping show, and away you go.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't figured out how to do it on a Mac, but for Windows w/ Powerpoint (maybeKeynote as well?) there's a way to do it without modifying any presentations - so you can chain multiple files on the fly! I've used this during symposiums at my university where I have 15 minutes to cue 10 presentations.

Our configuration had only a PC with single monitor, so you never got to see "Presenter's View" and have the luxury of a hidden screen to control things. There may be a more elegant way using a laptop or extended desktop, but the principles are the same.

Windows lets you have multiple .ppt's open in separate windows, even in presentation mode. As a presentation ends, the window disappears, revealing the most recent open window.

The key is using the Alt+Tab shortcut to switch between windows. When you hold the Alt key, tapping Tab cycles through all open windows. When you release Alt, the selected window becomes active (in front). When you go  full-screen/presentation mode it creates a second window, so you'll see both the editing window icon and the presentation icon as you scroll.

Then the trick is to have all the presentations you intend to display opened in reverse order so that when the first presentation (last opened) closes, the second one (second to last opened) is revealed.

To get things set up, open all presentations in edit-mode (so not fullscreen). It also helps for sanity to rename the presentations to start with 1,2,3, etc if you're doing more than two.

Next, hold Alt then hit Tab to select the last presentation you'll need, then release Alt. Hit F5 (shortcut for Present from First Slide).
Then Alt+Tab to select the second to last one. Hit F5 and it covers the last. Proceed until your first presentation is open and ready.

Once the first presentation has finished, I believe the next presentation appears ready to go. If it takes you to its editing window (or if presenter hits Esc to end their presentation, you'd just need to quickly Alt+F4  to close that editing view window or Shift+F5 to restart it from current slide.

If you have a presentation that loops to beginning, or someone who doesn't end on their last slide so it hangs open... just ALt+F4 to kill that window. You can always Alt+Tab your way through as you go but it's not as seamless.

It's a delicate house of cards, but it worked flawlessly for me 9/10 times. How well you rehearse and practice different scenarios will determine how awkward that 10th time goes. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

with Auto Presentation Switcher you can easily switch between presentations that are displayed in fullscreen. Just sort the presentations in a folder, then use shortcuts Ctrl+rightarrow (PC) or Command + rightarrow (mac) to display the next presentation. With the «seamless mode» enabled on the PC-version, the switch will look like a cut-transition between two slides.
https://presentationtools.com/aps
Disclaimer: I work for PresentationTools